# WooCommerce Print Invoice & Packing List Regular Price

Tags: woocommerce, invoice

I am using WooCommerce Print Invoice & Packing List plugin with Woocommerce to print invoices.I need to print the REGULAR PRICE of the product in the invoice.Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Got this to work
Add the following code to your invoice.php -

```
$item['product']->regular_price
```

Answer (score 0):

To add Regular Price to your invoice for each product, simply add the following code to your invoice.php file, right beneath the *dl* tag for SKU.

In my example, I'm labeling it "Unit Price". Feel free to change that if you want.

```
    <dl class="meta">
        <?php $description_label = __( 'Unit Price', 'wpo_wcpdf' ); // registering alternate label translation ?>
        <?php if( !empty( $item['product']->regular_price ) ) : ?><dt class="sku"><?php _e( 'Unit Price:', 'wpo_wcpdf' ); ?></dt><dd class="sku"><?php echo $item['product']->regular_price; ?></dd><?php endif; ?>
    </dl>
```